# Non blocking download of file in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am making a drop box like service using openstack. I am making a web interface using flask. User gets the object data in content of get request. I am sending data to the user iteratively. But my Flask app stops until the whole object is dowloaded. How could I make it non blocking?

```
#Returns the json content 
r = swift_account.getObject(container_name, object_name) 
filename = r.headers['X-Object-Meta-Orig-Filename']
#Make a generator so that all the content are not stored at once in memory
def generate():
    for chunk in r.iter_content():
        yield chunk

response = make_response(Response(stream_with_context(generate())))
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + filename
return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether flask runs as blocking or non-blocking depends how you run it. When you say it blocks, how are you running it?

Unless it's being run by something with async capabilities like gunicorn with async or at least a threading model for multiple requests like apache with mod_wsgi then it won't be able to respond to more than one request at a time.

Comment: Thanks danny. I ran my server as threaded one and now its working perfectly. Now I came to know Flask is neither blocking nor non blocking, it runs as you run it.